# Bluetooth low energy - Input/output error

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

When I do

`hcitool lescan`

sometimes I saw this error

```
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
or
Set scan parameters failed: File descriptor in bad state
```

I know i can reset the bluetooth interface.

However, is it possible to see the log or get any information to know the root cause of this error?

Thanks

Comment: The first one comes up if you try running `hcitool lescan` and there's already a scan in process.  There's a monitoring tool (can't recall the name) that dumps all HCI activity that may be able to help you determine the cause.  Basically, though, it's likely some other process using the bluetooth adapter.

Comment: @TimTisdall thanks Tim. If you have any further comment, please reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more information using BlueZ's `hcidump` and `btmon` command line tools. You can find more information here:-

- [btmon usage](http://manpages.org/btmon)
- [hcidump usage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hcidump)